# How do I make generator functions work with Hapi JS

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, hapi.js

I installed various node.js versions with nvm and tried -harmony flag to make generator functions work with yield keyword but I'm getting all kinds of errors when the server starts. One of them is below:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/joi/lib/object.js:310                                                                                                           
            throw castErr;                                                                                                                                                            
                  ^                                                                                                                                                                   
TypeError: Cannot read property '_items' of undefined                                                                                                                                 
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/topo/lib/index.js:39:22                                                                                                  
    at Array.forEach (native)                                                                                                                                                         
    at internals.Topo.add (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/topo/lib/index.js:36:24)                                                                             
    at internals.Object.keys (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/joi/lib/object.js:301:18)                                                                         
    at internals.root.root.object (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/joi/lib/index.js:71:72)                                                                      
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/catbox/lib/policy.js:255:24)                                                                         
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)                                                                                                                                             
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)                                                                                                                               
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)                                                                                                                                                 
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

Is there something special I need to do to use the yield keyword?

**UPDATE:** I updated nodejs to 5.4.1 and the errors are gone. But I can't use the yield function.

Here's a code:

```
var nodes = yield Db.node.find({ type: 'root' });
return reply.success(nodes);
```

And here's the error I get:

```
var nodes = yield Db.node.find({ type: 'root' });                                                                                                                              
                      ^^                                                                                                                                                              

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: Which Node.JS version are you using?

Comment: Because Node 0.12 doesn't support generators at all, and Node 4.0 and 5.0 doesn't support it fully. See https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: Also would be helpful to include some code that fails.

Comment: @Gothdo I tried with 0.12.7 and 4.1.1.

Comment: @MattHarrison I don't even have a yield code. The server starts successfully when I remove the -harmony flag. So I don't think it's about the code I wrote.

Comment: Please see the update guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a plugin for hapi that allows you to run a generator as handler. Something like https://github.com/ide/hapi-async-handler